# ¿Es posible generar JSON desde Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json

¿Existe alguna forma de realizar el JSON encode que hay en PHP, pero desde JavaScript o jQuery?

Necesito pasar un array que creo desde JavaScript mediante una conexión Ajax que mando por POST, y luego esta petición la transformo mediante PHP en una petición GET, por eso quiero tener el array en una cadena de texto, para no tener en una variable GET cada posicion del array.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Debes usar `JSON.stringify`, esto convierte cualquier estructura javascript (arrays u objetos) a su representación en formato JSON.

Ejemplo:

```js
console.log(
   JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5])
);

console.log(
   JSON.stringify({hola: "mundo"})
);
```

Nota: No es un componente de Jquery sino que es una API presente en los 
browsers.

Comment: Ya lo he probado y me ha funciona correctamente, muchas gracias